# How to make the words located within a scrollable ActiveX Control Text Box searchable?

Tags: vba, ms-word, developer-tools

In word 2016, I created a scrollable text box by using the developer tool. The Control I used is the ActiveX Control Text Box. When I click "Ctrl F," I am not able to find the text within the Text Box. What should I do so that I can find the text within these scroabble ActiveX Text Boxes? Do I need to write some VBA code or is it just a simple fix?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466953/how-to-make-ctrl-f-include-the-text-in-activex-controls-text-box

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls store the text within its binary file, which is not searchable by Word's Find and Replace utility. You can search it using VBA.

```
Sub FindReplaceText()
  AXText$ = TextBox1.Value
  If InStr(1, AXText$, "text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    AXText$ = Replace(AXText$, "text", "fish")
  End If
  TextBox1.Value = AXText$
End Sub
```